# Access previous arguments in RXJS operator chain

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm using Angular 5 and RXJS 5.5.5 together with ngrx/store to load reference data for my application. I can successfully load the data through an ngrx effect that takes an action with an id as payload, `map` it and then make a call to my service function. My problem is that I need the id used in the service call, after it has been done. I can't figure out how to access it later in the chain. I've tried to use `mergeMap` as that felt logical to me, but with no success.

How can I access `id` where I indicated in the code below?

```
@Effect()
loadReferences$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(LOAD_REFERENCES)
  .pipe(
    map((action: LoadReferences) => action.payload),
    switchMap((id) => this.service.loadReferences(id).pipe(
      map((references) => {
        // How can I access 'id' here?
        return new LoadReferencesSuccessful(references);
      }),
      catchError((err, caught) => {
        return LoadReferencesFailed(caught);
      })
    ))
  );
```

Comment: Since your comment is within the switchMap you should still have access to the scope for the `id` variable. Have you tried debugging or putting a console.log there to check its value?

Comment: You're correct. I feel embarrassed to admit the error, but as you can see I've omitted the ` { } `in my arrow function, which causes the block to be isolated. Simply wrapping the service call with `{ }` made everything work okay!

Comment: You sure it wouldn't work without that? If you exclude the `{}` it just does an explicit return of the expression. I don't think it has any bearing on scope. Like in this example the inner function still has access to "a": `((a) => (b) => { console.log(a, b); })(1)(2);`

Comment: You're right! I got errors previously but perhaps I was to quick to assume that was the error! Thanks for pointing that out @bygrace!